# Gson Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 492

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having an issue when converting an array from json to object. The exception is: Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 492

I searched the forum but for the cases that I found, none helped to solve this issue.

This is the checklist that is going to be parsed: http://pastebin.com/9kyk6hmu

This JSON is the same one that is generated through the Gson object itself, I put both in winmerge to check if there was anything wrong and there wasn't.

This is how I am doing the conversion to Json:

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ChecklistItemConverterAdapterFactory());              

    Gson convert = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    return convert.toJson(actvChecklist);
```

And to convert back to the checklist object:

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ChecklistItemConverterAdapterFactory());              
    Gson convert = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    CheckList answeredChecklist = convert.fromJson(checkListAnswer, CheckList.class);
```

The full stack is here: http://pastebin.com/vhLGG0mV

Is there any further configuration that should be done in order to this conversion to work properly?

This is the converter curstom adapter factory:

```
public class ChecklistItemConverterAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

@Override
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();
    if (rawType == CheckListItemFileType.class) {
        return new checklistItemFileTypeAdapter<>();
    }
    return null;
}

public class checklistItemFileTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        CheckListItemFileType fileType = (CheckListItemFileType) value;
        // Here write what you want to the JsonWriter.
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("value");
        out.value(fileType.name());
        out.name("pattern");
        out.value(fileType.getPattern());
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your adapter probably doesn't serialize/deserialize symmetrically.

Comment: I didn't paid enough attention to the read part, I am doing some search to find out how to create it properly since it is a complex object

Comment: Yes, the problem was purely in the adapter, it worked after I implemented the missing part.